# Specify PORT in Django Dockerfile using Cloudrun

Tags: django, docker, port, google-cloud-run

I have a basic Django 2 app (the starterproject) running locally in a Docker container.  This works fine and i can access site.

I would like to deploy the container using Google Cloudrun service and I see in their documentation it's required to specify the PORT environment variable.  I have tried many differnet configurations but I just cannot make it work.  I always get the error:

`Cloud Run error: Container failed to start. Failed to start and then listen on the port defined by the PORT environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.`

The logs have no information.

My base Docker file is:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
RUN chown -R user:user /app
RUN chmod 755 /app
USER user
```

and my docker-compose file is:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports: 
      - "$PORT:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

The troubleshooting is here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting

Where and how do i use the PORT environment variable correctly?

All help appreciated, Jon

Comment: Are the logs actually empty or it contains data but it does not seem to be useful ? if it contains data please add it to your question

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#port), your code that starts the HTTP server should consider its own environment's PORT variable.  The docs also say that, in practice, PORT will always be 8080, but your code should use the env var anyway for portability.

You might want to look at the [Python quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#writing).  Each of the examples there show how to access the PORT env var for their respective languages and runtimes.

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks I saw that buts it's using flask. I'm not a docker expert so I wondered how it could be done directly with the docker file / compose.  I have tried setting all ports to 8080 with no success.

Comment: It's not clear from the documentation that you have a choice in the matter.

Comment: @Jonnyboy - The value for the port that your service must use must be read from the environment variable PORT. This cannot be done in Dockerfile or docker-compose.yaml for Cloud Run. Right now the port defaults to 8080. If that does not work, then you have a problem with your code. Run your container locally in Docker and debug.